# php function to print only formatted numbers

Tags: php, regex, string, numbers

I need a simple function to pull out numbers from a string. Those numbers must be validated before being inserted into an array because there are different types of numbers.

For example:

> `$string ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in tortor dui, ac ornare tellus. Aenean condimentum eleifend commodo. Cras commodo magna a enim semper nec vulputate turpis ultricies. Etiam sodales urna quis mauris commodo gravida. Etiam eu varius ligula. Mauris in faucibus ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent aliquet, ligula et tristique vehicula, leo lorem accumsan nisl, vitae eleifend odio 1234 urna at magna. Integer 123456789 sit amet tincidunt enim. Curabitur eu tellus justo. Duis 987654321 vehicula tortor in eros consequat 12345 id lacinia lacus ornare.";`

What I need is to get an array with only these qualifying numbers:

- 123456789
- 987654321

Comment: Your question does not tell us what the rules of such a validation would be. Can you please tell what makes these numbers different from the others? Is it only their length?

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]{9}/", $string, $match);
print(implode("\n", $match[0]));
```

*For Education purpose*

```
echo implode("\n", array_filter(explode(" ", $string), function ($a) {
    return is_numeric($a) and strlen($a) == 9;
}));
```

Both would Output

```
123456789
987654321
```

Comment: thank you so much but what if want change the format so it can pull 11 number instead of only 9 ? for example "01123456789"

Comment: You would use `"/[0-9]{11}/"` instead

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match_all` is the function you're looking after.
The code below will match any numbers with 9 characters in length.

Here's an example:

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{9}/', $string, $matches);
echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
```

Which will result in:

```
123456789
987654321
```